# How to refactor following unless statement in Ruby

Tags: ruby

While learning Ruby, I got stucked with unless statement. Doing a full unless statement is sometimes too much. Please refactor the method below to use a single-line unless statement

```
games = ["Super Mario Bros.", "Contra", "Metroid", "Mega Man 2"]
unless games.empty?
  puts "Games in your vast collection: #{games.count}"
end
```

This code doesn't changes the `unless` statement to be inline, Please help me to modify this code so that it may work, Thanks.

Comment: @sawa Yet, I got my answer.

Comment: I didn't think that you were asking for something that simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use then

```
games = ["Super Mario Bros.", "Contra", "Metroid", "Mega Man 2"]
puts "Games in your vast collection: #{games.count}" unless games.empty?
# >> Games in your vast collection: 4
```

Comment: As a side note: these are called *statement modifiers*

Comment: Okay, let me check it, Thanks.

Comment: @MarianTheisen OP is checking if the array is*`empty* or not. Why any

Comment: @padde yes you are right,,

Comment: @priti it does the same, but reads better (to my eye). this is very subjective though.

Comment: @MarianTheisen `ary.empty?` and `!ary.any?` are not equivalent: `[nil].empty? #=> false` while `![nil].any? # => true`

Comment: @MarianTheisen try this `games = [nil]
puts "Games in your vast collection: #{games.count}" unless games.any?`

Comment: @toro2k Yes I just saw that... and remove my update.

Comment: @toro2k,@priti, yes you're right, and i know the difference ;) but, first of all, can this case ever happen? (it shouldnt) and second what is the desired behavior if it happens.